# Test to appear as login from different timezone(country)

Tags: sharepoint-online, date-time, login

how you can make think SharePoint that you have logged in from different country. Currently i am in USA east cost. How to log into SharePoint appearing from logging in from UK

Answer (score 1):

At our site, we could go to https://mysites.staff.com/Person.aspx and there was a link to edit your profile (including time zone). This link also may have worked https://mysites.staff.com/_layouts/15/EditProfile.aspx.

Substitute mysites.staff.com with your URL and have a go.

This option was later turned off at our site.